How to optimize the function below so that it might run under 1 second
Below is a code that makes a network where each node of the network is a Stuart-Landau oscillator. The equations of evolution are coupled and also depend on it's neighbors. The code runs 10^6 iterations under 20 seconds. I want to know whether it would be possible to run it under 1 second. Ideally the ultimate goal is to run 100000 different network geometries and get an averaged picture of its dynamics. The mean-square deviation needs to be averaged at least a million times. Since each time this function run takes 20 seconds, it's hard to run it a million times. I also want to know whether the problem can be solved using any GPU acceleration
import numpy as np
import random
from numba import jit
import time

start = time.time()
# function that generates the adjacency matrix
@jit(nopython=True)
def generate(n, m, p, seed):
    a = [1]*m
    cc = m // 2
    a.insert(cc, 0)
    b = a + [0]*( n - ( m + 1 ) )
    master_list = np.zeros((n,n))
    master_list[0] = np.roll(b, -cc)

    for i in range(1, n):
        master_list[i] = np.roll(master_list[i-1], 1)

    
    #Randomizes the links in the regular ring with monte-carlo approach
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random_list = np.random.uniform(0,1,(n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        
        row = master_list[i].copy()
        zeros = np.where(row == 0)[0]
        
        rand_row = (random_list[i] * row < p) * (row > 0).astype(np.int64)
        # setting the selected values to 0
        master_list[i][rand_row == 1] = 0

        length = np.sum(rand_row)
        
        # I have to remove the self term from the 0's list
        rem = list(np.where(zeros==i)[0])
        zeros = np.delete(zeros,rem)
        
        zero_choice = np.random.choice(zeros, length,replace=False)
        new_values = np.array([1] * length, dtype=np.float64)

        master_list[i][zero_choice] = new_values
    return master_list

# Stuart Landau Oscillator function
@jit(nopython=True)
def func(X,Y,G,w,c,e):
    n=2.0
    x_coup = (np.dot(G,X)-n*X)*(e/n)
    dxdt = (X-Y*w)-(X+Y*c)*(X**2+Y**2) + x_coup
    dydt = (Y+X*w)-(Y-c*X)*(X**2+Y**2)

    return(dxdt,dydt)

# RK4 integration function
@jit(nopython=True)
def RK4(X_0,Y_0,G,dt,w,c,e):
    k1,l1 = func(X_0,Y_0,G,w,c,e)
    k2,l2 = func(X_0+k1*dt/2,Y_0+l1*dt/2,G,w,c,e)
    k3,l3 = func(X_0+k2*dt/2,Y_0+l2*dt/2,G,w,c,e)
    k4,l4 = func(X_0+k3*dt,Y_0+l3*dt,G,w,c,e)

    new_X = X_0 + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*dt/6
    new_Y = Y_0 + (l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)*dt/6

    return new_X,new_Y


# Runs the function for 10^6 time steps
@jit(nopython=True)
def SL_evolve_random(w,c,e,adj_params,ti,t,dt,seed=155):
    (n,m,p,adj_seed)  = adj_params
    # the total number of oscillators
    adj = generate(n,m,p,adj_seed)     
    # Initial state
    choices=np.array([-1.0, 1.0])
    np.random.seed(seed)
    X = np.random.choice(choices, size=n)
    np.random.seed(seed + 451)
    Y = np.random.choice(choices, size=n)


    for _ in range(0,ti,1):
        X,Y = RK4(X,Y,adj,dt,w,c,e)

    #Calculates the mean-square-deviation value for 2000 time steps
    msd_vals = np.ones(t,dtype="float64")
    for i in range(0,t,1):
        X,Y = RK4(X,Y,adj,dt,w,c,e)
        msd = np.mean((X-np.mean(X))**2)
        msd_vals[i] = msd
    

    return(np.mean(msd_vals))

w=2
c=15
e=20
n=50
m=2
p=0.9
adj_seed=789
ti=int(1e6)
t=200
dt=0.01

s = SL_evolve_random(w,c,e,(n,m,p,adj_seed),ti,t,dt)
end = time.time()  
print("time taken = ",end-start)
print(s)

I want the code to run under 1-2 seconds

You should almost never reseed the random-number generator. Especially not with the same seed over and over. Unless you want the exact same sequence being generated. Or worse only the same number over and over if you seed before every random number you get.

There may be some optimisations (I don't understand the science here) but I can tell you that your code (without modification) runs in just over 6 seconds on Apple M2. I deduce therefore that a higher performance platform (M3 maybe?) will get you close to your objective

I believe when using jit, the first time you run the function it will be much slower than all consecutive runs. So run them maybe once before timing them with minimal values.

@oskar that would depend on whether you cache the JIT'd code or not
